# How to set css via jquery for preventing some action

Tags: jquery, css

Please refer the below link.

[How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting/4358620#4358620)

The above link is useful to disable selection  while dragging. code  snippet.

```
.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

but i don't want to use css concept here. i want to set these attributes for particular element via jquery. how can i do this ?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: jQuery has great documentation, I recommend to read it: http://api.jquery.com/css/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this

```
("#yourId").css({
           -moz-user-select: none;
           -khtml-user-select: none;
           -webkit-user-select: none;
           user-select: none;
 });
```

It is better to use class though

Your css class:

```
.unselectable{
       -moz-user-select: none;
       -khtml-user-select: none;
       -webkit-user-select: none;
       user-select: none;
}
```

Your Jquery command

```
$("#yourElementId").addClass('unselectable')
```

Answer (score 0):

use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> Get the value of a style property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for every matched element.

```
$('#elementsId').css({
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
 });
```

or make a class and use [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) ..cleanest way..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.addClass()`:

```
$(yourelem).addClass('unselectable');
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming jQuery and jQueryUI present, `$("#yourDomElement").disableSelection()` will do just that